# Automatically format C++ code with a lot of parenthesis((())) to multi-line (easier to read)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Sometimes, I want to reformat a line of code to multi-line for readability.

**For example:-**

```
pushBuffer( MouseEvent(globalVar()->timestamp,getButtonCode(in1,in2),PRESS));
```

might be formatted to :-

```
pushBuffer(
    MouseEvent(
        globalVar()->timestamp,
        getButtonCode(
            in1,
            in2
        ),
        PRESS
    )
);
```

**Question:** How to do it automatically in Visual Studio 2015?  Hotkey?

The closest feature is `ctrl+K ctrl+F` (Format Selection) which can format only indentation but never split code into such multiple lines.

**Edit:**
In my opinion, bolov's answer will lead me to a correct solution.  Thank!
However, as bolov mentioned, it is not a complete solution ; a custom script may be required.
I am investigating more about the script at a related [Visual Studio's Site](https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2013/11/05/format-c-code-intelligently-in-visual-studio-with-clang-format/).

**Edit (April, 2019):**
The original problem is not solved.
Furthermore, the problem is more intensified with `template<>`.

I also wish to split the line like this (or similar) :-

```
template<
    class T,
    class B=T::F<
        W
    > 
>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Clang format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) is an excellent tool and it has a [Visual Studio extension](http://llvm.org/builds/). The default shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.

It is highly customizabile, but in general it will not split a line unless it exceeds the column limit.

Here are some examples of what it can do (I made the names longer so that it goes over the column limit):

```
pushBuffer_long_name(
    MouseEvent_long_name(globalVar_long_name()->timestamp_long_name,
                         getButtonCode_long_name(in1, in2), PRESS_long_name));
```

I think there is an option to keep each argument on a separate line if it can't keep them all on a line. You'll have to play with it.